# New release stuck at "Ready to send for review" after play store removed the app

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, privacy-policy

My app was recently removed from the play store for ***missing the privacy policy*** inside the app.

> APK REQUIRES VALID PRIVACY POLICY​
> Your app is uploading users' Primary Account information to ************ without posting a privacy policy in both the designated field in the Play Developer Console and from within the Play distributed app itself.

I fixed this issue in the app and created a new release, but for some reason, the status of the review is stuck at **Ready to send for review**. How do I change this to **In review**?

Answer (score 285, accepted):

You need to go to publishing overview (left side under dashboard) and confirm again. Then the status should change to "in review" after a while.

Pretty unintuitive, nothing else points to that.

Comment: @PratikBaid same happens with me, do we have to make changes in Facebook, Google Sign in as it directly goes inside the app without T&C??

Comment: @RohitSingh you can use https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com/ to generate the privacy policy as they cover the case where you are using 3rd party login provider. I also had an option for users to view the privacy policy inside the app.

Comment: Google's objection bots are more unreasonable than usual lately seeing as how many are getting this issue in just the last few months, and of course the unintuitive extra step solution towards progress. I've been suddenly held up for 'objectionable content gruesome images' for a mild in-game image of skeletons I've had up on the Google Play site for 2 years.

Comment: UX experience is worse

Comment: Thanks!  Just been through the same rigmarole.  It's as if they're deliberately making life complicated for developers.

Comment: I arrived to this answer today when I was searching why the 'send for review' button was not appearing. if you're having the same problem, don't panic (like I did), it will appear in hour or so. I have no idea why and it's pretty crappy ux, google is just being google!